# Setting the value of a FormControl breaks its type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have this `FormGroup` with this `FormControl`

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(this.user.id),
    firstName: new FormControl(this.user.firstName),
    lastName: new FormControl(this.user.lastName),
    email: new FormControl(this.user.email),
    password: new FormControl(""),
    userRole: new FormControl(this.user.userRole)
});
```

`this.user.userRole` is a number and the FormControl `userRole` maps to a C# enum in the back end.

When I submit this form like this, it works, I get the proper data in the action method with the correct value for the enum.

But when I change the value of the userRole FormControl, like this:

```
changeRole(e) {
    this.userForm.get('userRole').setValue(parseInt(e.target.value), {
        onlySelf: true
    });
}
```

This is triggered by a change event on a dropdown `select`.

The problem is when I then submit the form, the value is turned to a string. I can confirm this by looking in Chrome's network tab (when it works, `userRole: 10`, when it fails after the value in the UI was changed, `userRole: "10"`

This is how it's submitted to the controller:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.userService.save(this.userForm.value as User).subscribe(r => {
      this._bsModalRef.hide();
    });
}

//the service's method....
save(user: User): Observable<any> {
    let url = "/user/save";
    return this.http.post(url, user);
}
```

And the `User` class:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  userRoleDisplay: string;
  userRole: number;
  lastLogin: string;
  password: string
}
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: How did you get the value from the form? Can you check if after retrieving the value from the form it is a string or number?

Comment: @LeonardoAlves I added that part.

Comment: Try subscribing to `valueChanges` of userRole to check if something else is changing the  value of the control after the setValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume userRole is assigned to a `<select>` element, correct?

If yes, then use `[ngValue]` for the `<option>` elements instead of `[value]`.

`[value]` can only hold string values.

Comment: Correct, let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the userRole from string to number data type before submitting the form.

```js
onSubmit() {
    const user = this.userForm.value;
    
    // Convert userRole from string to number
    user.userRole = +user.userRole;
    
    this.userService.save(user as User).subscribe(r => {
      this._bsModalRef.hide();
    });
}
```